# Use |sin(x) − x| ≤ (1/6) |x|^3 to Calculate Limit Values

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

could someone explain what exactly this question is asking? I'm not sure how to use the given inequality to calculate arbitrary limit values of the given function?

Use the fact that |sin(x) − x| ≤ (1/6) |x|^3 to

calculate the limit for different values of a ∈ R and

c > 0 of the function f(x) = x^a * sin( |x|^−c ) as x → ∞

Comment: Use a new letter, you get a precise statement about $\sin {\frac{1}{t^c}}$ as $t$ goes to $+\infty,$  $$-\frac{1}{6t^{3c}}  + \frac{1}{t^c} \leq  \sin {\frac{1}{t^c}} \leq \frac{1}{t^c} + \frac{1}{6t^{3c}} $$